# MANUALLY remove notification observer for iOS 9.0 and later

Tags: swift

I would like to know if one can remove notification observer for iOS9.0 and later. Apple docs say that the notifications will automaticatically be removed once the view disappeared which is true but not totally true.
my tarBarController is calling UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification even if the view disappeared.

If there is a presentedViewController presented by tarBarController, the presentedViewController calls the notification AND the tarBarController does the same even if I remove the observer in my tarBarController

```
//TabBarController

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillDisappear(notification:)), name: UIScene.willDeactivateNotification, object: nil)
                          } else {
                              NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillDisappear(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
                          }
}



override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) // there is no need to remove this observer in iOS 9 and later , but TarBarController doesn't dealloc 

}




//PresentedViewController

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillDisappear(notification:)), name: UIScene.willDeactivateNotification, object: nil)
                          } else {
                              NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillDisappear(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
                          }
}



override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    // the presentedViewController removes this observer which is fine

}
```

Comment: `deinit { print("deinit called") }`
Check if this method is called when you leave the view controller, if this isn't called that means you have memory leak issues that needs to be resolved.

Comment: You’re right, my tabBarController doesn’t deallocate immediately, but the problem is I cant remove that notification observer manually. I don’t want to keep a weak reference to my tabBarController.